# jasmine-ajax mock get parameters

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-ajax

I am using jasmine-ajax to mock $.ajax get calls. In my actual code I send some parameters through the data options.

```
var request = $.ajax("/users", {
      data: {id:"1"},
});
```

but in my tests `jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().url` returns `/users?id=1` and `jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().data()` returns `{}`. Is there a way to make the url return `/users` and data return `{id:"1"}` to make my testing life easier?

Answer (score 0):

When using **GET** method for making a request, the query string is sent like this `/users?id=1`. But you should use **POST** method if you want to make your "testing life easier".

```
var request = $.ajax("/users", {
    method: "POST",
    data: {id:"1"},
});
```

See the resulting specs in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/EduardoRG/49ufpe3b/